# AND gate circuit using mosfet

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to design an AND gate using mosfet. But it failed at one state.
I did the same design with BJT and it works correctly.

You see when it's one end is high and the other is low, it gives a 3.3V which is not correct.
Other states works fine.

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown any actual voltages for the power supply or the logic inputs. Please indicate what the gate and drain voltages are for the three transistors in the MOSFET version.

Comment: You inverted the red 1 visually :-) ... Please strive to show your circuit to the best of your ability: text is read from left to right, turn off the grid, etc

Comment: @Huisman I attatched a better version

Comment: Legibility tips: (1) Turn off the grid before taking the screengrab. (2) Remove all unnecessary kinks in wiring. (3) Convention is to draw your circuit with logical flow so that it reads from left to right. (4) Q3 and Q4 could be aligned vertically. (4) Look out for wires going nowhere such as the one disappearing beneath Q4.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that your output is connected to drain of Q2, when Q2 is off you would like 0 as output. But the drain of Q2 is at the Power supply level (No current flowing in R1).

Add a resistor at the source of Q2 and take the output there. Choose a proper value for this resistor (larger than R1)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKyTiM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I changed the N-mos to P-mos in order to have AND, if you use a N-mos it's a NAND.

Values of resistor are random, i didn't check the proper values.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, can you show a simple schematic please

Comment: What is the other terminal of resistor should connect to?